# How do I create a .bin file for a given file in python?

Tags: python, binary, bin

I am looking to view and manipulate the 1s and 0s of a file. What I gather I need is to generate/view the .bin file of a given file, which could be anything from a photo to a document. How do I go about getting the .bin file for a file in my python code?

Comment: Are you familiar with Python's [file handling commands](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)? Try opening it, then read its contents. That ought to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

All files are technically "bin" files since they are simply a sequence of bytes.  Open the file with `open('name', 'rb')` so that it is in "binary" or raw mode.  See the documentation for [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for more information.  Then read the bytes into a variable using [`file.read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.read).  You can dump the binary representation of a file using something like the following:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def dump_file(name):
    with open(name, 'rb') as in_file:
        for data in in_file:
            for a_byte in data:
                print('{:08b}'.format(ord(a_byte)), end='')
        print('')
```